# How would you make the result print "computer wins" or "user wins"

Tags: javascript

Obviously, this will print out rock/paper/scissors wins or it's a tie.

What is the best way to achieve a result like "Rock beats scissors -- Computer wins!" and such?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
}

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

I have some knowledge of functions and variables that I think is enough to solve this -- I just can't figure it out. I have less than 8 hours of javascript experience.

Also, this is not my homework, I just finished a lesson in codecademy and wondered this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm just starting Javascript. I have some knowledge of functions and variables that I think is enough to solve this problem. I just can't figure it out. Also, no, not homework, just doing codecademy and this game was an exercise, what I'm asking here is just for personal study.

Comment: @NeedMoreNoodles you can create text elements and insert them into the page using the DOM. Alternatively, `alert()` (but that's annoying).

Comment: I posted an example solution below that shows the DOM insert method, but this would be fun to get really creative with and use images/icons for the rock, paper, and scissors, and show the results in a table with columns for cpu choice, player choice, and the victor (result).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into changing the strings in the program so instead of just "scissors wins" I would change that to "Scissors beats (insert corresponding choice here) - Player wins!!!"

You can find the corresponding choice by trial and error debugging or by following the logic of the nested if's and else's.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it by appending to the DOM.

This example uses a `do {} while ()` loop to keep asking the player if he wants to play, and if so asks for his choice. It then displays the result (tie or player / cpu wins) to the `output` element on the page. This method is nice because it keeps track of the plays for you, so if you need to do a "best 3 of 5" you can see who ultimately wins!

**jQuery jsFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/edahqpho/3/

Pure javascript jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/edahqpho/1/

HTML

```
<div id='output'></div>
```

Javascript (pure JS example)

```
function play() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
    return compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
}
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
}

var output = document.getElementById('output');
do {
    var result = play();
    var display = document.createElement("DIV");
    var text = document.createTextNode(result);
    display.appendChild(text);
    output.appendChild(display);
}
while (window.confirm("Play again?"));
```

This next snippet demonstrates a more advanced visualization of the game using similar DOM injecting techniques (which are waaaay easier with a library like jQuery).

```js
function play() {
do {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();
} while (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var playResult = {
    User: userChoice,
    CPU: computerChoice,
    Winner: compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
};
return playResult;
}
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "tie";
} else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "player";
    } else {
        return "cpu";
    }
} else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "player";
    } else {
        return "cpu";
    }
} else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
        return "player";
    } else {
        return "cpu";
    }
}
}

function getIcon(shape) {
    var url = "";
    switch (shape) {
        case "paper":
            url = "http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/256/rock-paper-scissors-paper-icon.png";
            break;
        case "rock":
            url = "http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/256/rock-paper-scissors-rock-icon.png";
            break;
        case "scissors":
            url = "http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/256/rock-paper-scissors-scissors-icon.png";
            break;
    }
    return url;
}

function game() {
    var $output = $("#output");
    var result = play();
    $output.append("<tr><td><img src='" + getIcon(result.User) + "'/></td><td><img src='" + getIcon(result.CPU) + "'/></td><td>" + result.Winner.toUpperCase() + "</td></tr>");
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Play again?")) {
            game()
        }
    }, 10);
}
// start the game of all games...
game();
```

```css
#output th, #output td {
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family:"Segoe UI", Arial, "Sans serif";
}
img {
width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='output'>
<tr>
    <th>Player</th>
    <th>CPU</th>
    <th>Winner</th>
</tr>
</table>
```